# SQL Server: Retrieve rows where the Prod Num is like a string found in a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

**GOAL:**
Our goal is to retrieve a list of all sales activity for any PN that begins with any targeted prod series.
In the [**SqlFiddle found here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11502/1), this would return rows 1 through 4 from the `Sales` table.
The targeted product series are currently on a spreadsheet, which I'll probably just import it into a temp table or something to simplify querying.

**OVERVIEW:**
Here's a simplification of our sales history table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales ([id] int, [pn] varchar(9), [qty] int, [price] int);
```

Feel free to [fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11502/1)

Let's presume we have a product series called ABC for which there are multiple counts, such as ABC-100ct and ABC-200ct.
The spreadsheet only contians series numbers, such as ABC.

If it was a one-off, I would simply query where `CONTAINS` or `LIKE`, but there are around 155 series being targeted.

**QUESTION:**
How do I query for rows where the PN begins with a string found in any row in a different table?

**[EDIT]**
BTW, our series numbers are of various lengths. I realize that the sample provided didn't really convey that, but they vary considerably.
**[/EDIT]**

Comment: Are the product line numbers always followed by a dash?

Comment: By and large, yes. There are definitely exceptions, but _most_ of the prod nums do have that dash.

Comment: So is there *any* reliable way of extracting the product series code from an arbitary `pn`? Joining with an equality predicate can sometimes be a better performing option as it allows hash or merge join.

Comment: Unfortunately, the series numbers are created by our vendors which span multiple industries, so it really is all over the place :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use like in your join criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales S
  JOIN temp t ON s.pn like t.pn + '%'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11502/2)

Comment: Nice, I've never seen that before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can join on substrings if you can come up with a function to get the product series reliably out of the product code.  For example, if it is always the first three characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
JOIN temp on left(Sales.pn, 3) = temp.pn
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11502/3

Comment: Great solution! Unfortunately I neglected to mention that our series numbers are of an unpredictable length. That info has now been edited into the question. Thanks.